# Generalized Wieferich primes, a question of existence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Peter was typing something about Wieferich primes, that is primes $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$.

In the Wikipedia it is stated : *As of September 2018, the only known Wieferich primes are 1093 and 3511*

I arrived at the idea of considering more general problem.

Let $p$ be a prime such that $a \geq 2$ and $p \leq a$ and there exists $1<k\leq p$ such that $p^k$ divides $a^{p-1}-1$

Denote such a $p$ as $W(a,k)$ so that Wieferich primes are $W(2,2)$

To do a basic research this question could be asked:

Find at least some pairs $(a,k)$ for which we have that $W(a,k)$ exists?

Comment: For $k=2$ , for most bases we know a prime doing the job. The smallest bases for which no prime is known (and therefore neither for $k>2$) are $47$ and $72$. For larger $k$, I do not know the current status.

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-250/S0025-5718-04-01666-7/S0025-5718-04-01666-7.pdf